# Create a hive table in my user location using the hdfs files in other location

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have following requirements: 
 - I want to Create a hive table in my user location using the hdfs files in other location. 
 - I want to copy and not move the files as it is shared by other users.
 - The files are already stored by date folder. Each day a new folder will be created and there will be 'n' number of csv files inside the day folder. I want my table to be holding those files data partitioned by date field
 - After one time table being created, i want the table to be updated everyday with that day's files

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Lookup [external tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ManagedandExternalTables)

Comment: Not clear. Why would you want to create a copy of the data?

Comment: your requirements are not clear.. do you have permission over the other table? why you want to copy those files to your persona hdfs folder? are you expecting to see the new data without any process updating your table?

Comment: i dont have permission over the other table. i can't add/alter partitions. So any recent dated partitions cannot be seen.But in the folder/path I can see the files for recent dates. Recent dated data will be visible to  me only when table owner updates the partitions. To avoid this dependency i want to create my own table. Please let me know if you need more details i can explain.